How to match different patterns in a regular expression
I want to add regex to one of my projects which allows for multiple patterns and matchers.
I currently have an enum that stores types:
public enum Types {

   OAK_DOOR,
   BIRCH_DOOR,
   BAMBOO_DOOR,
   CAKE,
   RANDOM,
   WHITE_BED,
   RED_BED,
   PINK_BED,
   BLACK_BED;

}

Here is my current code:
public Set<String> getTypes() {
    Set<String> foundTypes = Sets.newHashSet();
    List<String> regexPatterns = Lists.newArrayList("^.*?_BED", "^.*?_DOOR");

    for (String regexPattern : regexPatterns) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);

        for (Types type : Types.values()) {
            String name = type.name();
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(name);

            while (m.find()) {
                 foundTypes.add(m.group());
            }
        }
    }

    return foundTypes;
}

This is not returning any values from the Types enum.
What am I doing wrong?

I've tried your code, and it works fine for me (returning [BIRCH_DOOR, PINK_BED, RED_BED, BLACK_BED, WHITE_BED, OAK_DOOR, BAMBOO_DOOR]). Maybe the problem is with the caller, and not this method. Please provide a [mre].

BTW you can use String.endsWith() in this particular use case

If you want to match types ending in either DOOR or BED, then just use a single regex pattern:
_(?:DOOR|BED)$

Updated Java code:
public Set<String> getTypes() {
    Set<String> foundTypes = Sets.newHashSet();
    String regexPattern = "_(?:DOOR|BED)$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);

    for (Types type : Types.values()) {
        String name = type.name();
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(name);

        if (m.find()) {
             foundTypes.add(m.group());
        }
    }

    return foundTypes;
}


By replacing your code List regexPatterns from guava to java sdk properly , the following changes work smoothly. It might also work with guava but you actually dont need it since it works with the native lib.
List<String> regexPatterns = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("^.*?_BED", "^.*?_DOOR"));


The OP is using Guava's Lists.newArrayList(...) which does the equivalent, so this is not relevant to the problem of the OP.

And there is the problem that caused issue. Changing that to native java has resolved the op problem. There is no issue in using native java instead of guava since it resolved the probelm

But the variant with Guava as presented in the question works just as well (I double-checked). And Lists.newArrayList creates a java.util.ArrayList (and even if it didn't, it wouldn't matter as long as it correctly implements List).

BTW Arrays.asList() already returns a list, no need for for new ArrayList() (unless we need it to be modifiable, not the case as given in the question)

@MarkRotteveel yes the line he mentioned refers to guava, but op nowhere mentioned that he needs guava, instead he mentioned java. So basically there is no point for argument here.

Guava is a library for Java, so they're still using Java.

Yes you are so right !

If what you need is a list of Types you must make some small changes to your code:
  // change the type of the "Set"
public Set<Types> getTypes() {

     // change the type of the "Set"
   Set<Types> foundTypes = new HashSet();
   List<String> regexPatterns = List.of( "^.*?_BED", "^.*?_DOOR" );

   for( String regexPattern: regexPatterns ) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regexPattern );

      for( Types type: Types.values() ) {
         String name = type.name();
         Matcher m = pattern.matcher( name );

         while( m.find() ) {
             
              // change the returned object
            foundTypes.add( type );
         }
      }
   }
   return foundTypes;
}

